# How to find closest locations on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to create an app where users can add locations and see locations. I want that when a user opens the app only the closest locations to the user's current location appear (say within a radius of 200m). How can I do something like that? I understand this question is extremely vague, I just want tips on how I could do this.

Answer (score 0):

use: https://pub.dev/packages/geodesy

```
Geodesy geodesy = Geodesy();

List<Location> locations = [...];  // Your list of locations
List<Location> nearbyLocations = [];

void getNearbyLocations() async {
  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  LatLng userLocation = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

  for (Location location in locations) {
    LatLng locationLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
    double distance = geodesy.distanceBetweenTwoGeoPoints(userLocation, locationLatLng);
    if (distance <= 200) {  // distance in meters
      nearbyLocations.add(location);
    }
  }
}
```